# UIView Extension to Center View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In my viewcontroller I can center a textField with:

`textField.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: textField.center.y)`

Why doesn't my extension work:

```
extension UIView {
    func centerHorizontally() {
    self.center = CGPoint(x: self.superview!.bounds.midX, y: self.center.y)
}


// back in viewcontroller
emailField.centerHorizontally()
```

Comment: "Why doesn't my extension work" What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Why you dont use AutoLayout ?

Comment: @matt it just doesn't center the textfield

Comment: Yes, but your job is to show how you are testing. Because I can prove to you that it _does_ work — if you call `emailField.centerHorizontally()` under the right circumstances.

Comment: Odd code. You center X by looking at the superview's bounds, but you center Y by... itself? Does this code work at all?(Minor quibble: you left out a right curly bracket in your extension code - what you posted *certainly* wouldn't build.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* work.

[image]

This is the only code in my app:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.emailField.centerHorizontally()
}
```

The problem is that you are testing incorrectly. Unfortunately you have not given any information on *how* you are testing. But some possibilities are:

- You are calling `emailField.centerHorizontally()` *too soon*, e.g. in `viewDidLoad`, when the field's superview's bounds are not yet set to their ultimate values.
- You have positioned `emailField` using autolayout. You cannot change the `center` of a view that is under the influence of autolayout.
- You might not be taking into account the fact that the text field's *text* is left-aligned.
- Other...

Comment: I'm calling the extension method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` now

Comment: Don't talk about your code. _Show your real code._

Comment: Meanwhile I've posted a screen shot proving that your code does indeed center the field.

Comment: And can you confirm that you have selected your storyboard and un-checked the "use auto-layout" checkbox? Storyboards use auto-layout by default, and unless you turn it off explicitly the OS will add constraints to your views even if you don't do so.

Comment: @DuncanC Actually no, that doesn't happen any more. In the screen shot above, the storyboard does use autolayout.

Comment: @matt sorry. The issue was that I had this textField inside a container view but did not properly adjust the size of the container.